# Join 2nd Table with Less Than, Order Desc Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a weblog that captures visits to my website:

```
Table weblog
id  logdate    browser  ipaddr         inet_aton_ip
 1  2013-05-01 Chrome   42.61.66.124      708657788
 2  2013-05-01 Chrome   217.9.192.99     3641294848
 3  2013-05-02 Firefox  77.79.58.77      1297037901
...etc...
```

I downloaded the ip2nation database which lets me look up the country based on the inet_aton_ip value:

```
mysql> select * from ip2nation where ip<708657788 order by ip desc limit 1;
+-----------+---------+
| ip        | country |
+-----------+---------+
| 708575232 | sg      |
+-----------+---------+
mysql> select * from ip2nation where ip<3641294848 order by ip desc limit 1;
+------------+---------+
| ip         | country |
+------------+---------+
| 3641286656 | uk      |
+------------+---------+
... and so on ...
```

The ip column in ip2nation marks an IP boundary, so the search is not precise, i.e. an equal comparison would not work.  This structure makes sense, as for a subnet like 42.61.66.x, they don't have to list 255 similar entries.

Using a C# routine like

```
DataTable dt = [a sql function to select * from weblog]
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     long ipnum = int.Parse(row["inet_aton_ip"].ToString());
     string cty = [a sql function to select country using ipnum]
}
```

I can get the following table:

```
id  logdate    browser  ipaddr         inet_aton_ip  country
 1  2013-05-01 Chrome   42.61.66.124      708657788  sg
 2  2013-05-01 Chrome   217.9.192.99     3641294848  uk
 3  2013-05-02 Firefox  77.79.58.77      1297037901  lt
```

I wonder if I can generate the above table using one sql instead of two sqls, like in the C# routine?  I tried playing with subselects and joins but each time I get thrown off by the "ip less than x order by ip desc limit 1" portion.  Would appreciate any pointers from SQL experts here.

Answer (score 0):

If we have `ip2nation` table then you can join both tables like this:

```
SELECT w.*, ip.country
  FROM weblog w
  JOIN ip2nation ip
    ON w.inet_aton_ip = ip.ipp
```

Output:

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║          LOGDATE           ║ BROWSER ║    IPADDR    ║ INET_ATON_IP ║ COUNTRY ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ Chrome  ║ 42.61.66.124 ║    708657788 ║ sg      ║
║  2 ║ May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ Chrome  ║ 217.9.192.99 ║   3641294848 ║ uk      ║
║  3 ║ May, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ Firefox ║ 77.79.58.77  ║   1297037901 ║ lt      ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2124b/2)

Comment: Unfortunately, using equal would not work as the ip2nation table is ordered by ranges which may not result in an exact match.

Comment: Unfortunately, using equal would not work as the ip2nation table is ordered by ranges which may not result in an exact match.  So for example, the ip2nation may contain rows "708000000,sg" and "709000000,th".  Then the equal comparison would fail for 708657788.  But using the statement "ip<708657788 order by ip desc limit 1" would return "708000000,sg" as the result.

Comment: The weblog table structure is as I had shown in my question.  The ip2nation is a table with 2 columns (ip, country).  A "select * from ip2nation limit 5" returns this: (ip, country), (0, 'us'), (687865856, 'za'), (689963008, 'eg'), (691011584, 'za'), (691617792, 'zw').  The ip2nation table is an open source table that can be downloaded from the web.

Comment: @DavidOng - if `ip` column of the table `ip2nation` contains only integers like `691617792` then this query will work perfect.

Comment: That was my initial approach too. But after reading the ip2nation technotes, I realised the ip integers mark the boundaries, not the exact ip. Which makes sense as a subnet like 46.61.66.x can contain 255 individual ips. Referring to my answer two posts above, we have ip=687865856 => 'za', ip=689963008 => 'eg'. If I get an ip=689000000, it doesn't have an exact match in the table. But using the "ip less than x order by ip desc limit 1" rule, we end up with ip=689000000 => 'za'.  So I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately, the situation is more complicated.

Comment: Ok I realised the confusion.  Sorry that I miscopied the return values in my original question.  Will edit it now.  Please re-read.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `country` from table `ip2nation` by joining it directly using `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*. b.country
FROM    weblog a
        INNER JOIN ip2nation b
            ON a.inet_aton_ip = b.ipp
WHERE   b.ipp < 708657788 
order   by b.ipp
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: That only works for the first weblog row.  The second and third row has different numbers: 3641294848 and 1297037901 respectively.